# Изменения в шрифте при верстке

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять, почему при верстке ширина букв получается **у**же, чем было в макете

[image]

справа то что в макете, слева - в браузере, видно, что ширина букв в браузере получается меньше, хотя все настройки шрифта из макета в стили перенесены. Применение свойства font-stretch никакого влияния не оказало, ну и плюс к тому, использовать css3 не хотелось бы. Почему так получается и как на это повлиять?

Answer (score 1):

Браузеры применяют свойство font-stretch не ко всем шрифтам, поэтому уплотнение или расширение текста может не работать с некоторыми популярными и распространёнными гарнитурами шрифтов. Тем более, это свойство поддерживается IE9+ и FireFox, остальные браузеры игнорируют это свойство.
Используйте cyfon. Или переподбирайте шрифт.

Comment: мне помогла прописать шрифты не так font: bold 22px Georgia serif; а так font: bold 22px Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times serif;